# Is there any way to accelerate the caching process in pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to cache a Pyspark based data frame with 3 columns and 27 rows and this process is taking around 7-10 seconds.

Is there anyway to accelerate this job?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You could try any of the below approaches:

- coalesce your dataframe into a single partition for eg. `df.coalesce(1)` and then cache it
- Since your dataframe is pretty tiny you could load it as a pandas dataframe, which will be in memory. toPandas() could help you in that regards. Don't forget use the arrow spark setting to make it faster.
  `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "true")`
  `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")`

Comment: Thanks Yash, enabling arrow improved the performance a lot